# $(document).ready() does not work with Greasemonkey

Tags: jquery, greasemonkey

I am trying to build some code in jquery that won't work without specifying an event or function like `$(document).ready` function.

But while using the script in Greasemonkey I am unable to run the code the moment I enclose it in `$(document).ready` function. Is there a way out?

```
$('div').live('blur',function(){
 //the code goes here
});
```

Well the above code worked pretty fine but I don't want an even, just as soon as the page loads the code should run.

Comment: I can only assume you forgot to add the `);` on stackoverflow, else you're going to be laughing at yourself.

Comment: @tfbox Yea...Only on stackoverflow ..lol

Comment: Have you tried with calling **alert()** function in it.? is any error occur.?

Comment: @chandresh Well yes. The alert works fine without document ready function otherwise ther is no alert box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$ is unknown in GM, you'll need to access it using unsafeWindow:

```
    unsafeWindow.$('div').live('blur',function(){
     //the code goes here
    });
```

(Note that  usually blur will not fire on div-elements)

GM-scripts will be executed on DOMContentLoaded(What is the same like the ready-event of a document in jQuery )

http://wiki.greasespot.net/DOMContentLoaded

Comment: Good info but still did not answer my question. which asks for an alter event which does not require manual input by hovering or clicking etc. It should be automatic.

Comment: Take a look at the link in my post, the whole GM-script will be executed on DOMContentLoaded, that's an event without user-input. So you don't need to observe an event, GM already does.